# Bouncy Castle ECIES compatible?

Tags: bouncycastle

Ladar Levison wrote ecies_encrypt and ecies_decrypt C functions. Are these functions compatible with ECIES Bouncy Castle? If not, does anyone know what to fix or another C implementation of ECIES?

Answer (score 1):

In a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152555/encrypting-decrypting-text-strings-using-openssl-ecc), Ladar Levison mentioned that his implementation is "loosely" following ECIES. Therefore, 100% compatibility is rather unlikely.